# Index out of range error in collection view

Tags: json, swift, api, struct

I have a api which shows a particular data as follows

```
[
    {
        "sku": "BWBCL14KWGF003",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "139"
    },
    {
        "sku": "BWBCL14KWGF001",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "139"
    },
    {
        "sku": "BWBCL14KWGF002",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "139"
    }
]
```

The corresponding code in the swift is given below which uses struct

```
           AF.request("https://adamas-intl.com/rest/V1/categories/139/products", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

             let decoder = JSONDecoder()

             do {


                 let user = try decoder.decode(ProductlistDataModel.self, from: response.data!)
                self.ProductlistDataModelElement = user
                if self.ProductlistDataModelElement!.count > 0{

                    print("total no of products are",self.ProductlistDataModelElement?.count)


                    for items in 0..<self.ProductlistDataModelElement!.count
                    {
                        self.skuarray.append(self.ProductlistDataModelElement![items].sku)
                    }

                    for item in 0..<self.skuarray.count
                    {
                        self.getimages(sku: self.skuarray[item])

                    }



//                     self.collectionview1.delegate = self
//                     self.collectionview1.dataSource = self
//                     self.collectionview1?.reloadData()
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     self.navigationController?.view.makeToast("No Products in this category", duration: 3.0, position: .center)

                 }

             } catch {
                 print(error.localizedDescription)
             }


           }
```

This ProductlistDataModelElement is listing all the required values from this api.Now the data retrieved from this api is used in another api to fetch remaining values like price, images etc.
When i fetch from another api using self.getimages(sku: self.skuarray[item]).
The another api is as follows:

```
 func  getimages(sku: String){


        AF.request("https://adamas-intl.com/rest/V1/products/" + sku, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

                       //New
                       let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                       do {
                          let user = try decoder.decode(ProductDetailDataModel.self, from: response.data!)
                            self.detailmodel = user
                           // self.orgsearchDataModel = user

                           let price:Int = (self.detailmodel?.price)!

                            self.pricearray.append(String(price))

                             let array = self.detailmodel?.mediaGalleryEntries

                            let image = array![0].file

                             let imageurl = "https://adamas-intl.com/pub/media/catalog/product/" + image

                             self.imagearray.append(imageurl)

                         print("self.pricearray  is",self.pricearray.count)

                        if self.pricearray.count > 0
                        {
                             self.collectionview1.delegate = self
                             self.collectionview1.dataSource = self
                             self.collectionview1?.reloadData()
                        }

                       } catch {
                           print(error.localizedDescription)
                       }
                    }
     }
```

Here from this api code,the pricearray should have around 46 values as per the api.But the moment the value is 1,the collection view is reloaded.Hence in cellforitemat,it shows index out of range error.How to reload the collection view once it has retrieved all the values.

Comment: You have multiple arrays - skuarray, price array, ... - which one of these are you using to decide the number of items in collection view and populate it?

Comment: actually price array should decide.Because skuarray is got from first api and later using this skuarray in a for loop,another api is called and then pricearray is retrieved.

Comment: You are calling getimages() method from within a for loop iterating over skuarray. Say, the skuarray has x items, your getimages() method will be called x times and so the collection view will be reloaded x times. Is it intended?

Comment: yes i solved it.By equating both the array count.if true then it will reload.

Comment: Well, the problem with equating arrays (skuarray with pricearray) is that even if one the network request in the getimages() method fails, the collection view will never be reloaded as the array count will never match.

Comment: Then how to solve this issue.

Comment: How many sections are in the collection view? What value are you returning from numberOfItemsInSection method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214313/discussion-between-saranya-and-sats).